# How is dividing into minibatches implemented in batch normalization for deeper layers?

Tags: deep-learning

Suppose, we have dataset X (2D array), and we divide it into batches `X_1, ..., X_k`.
Then for each batch we do normalization, then each i-th component of batch element we multiply by parameter `gamma_i` and add to them `beta_i`.

Batch normalization layer can be repeated several times and I didn't found anything about how it is implemented deeper in network.

In next BN layers do we use the same division to batches as in the beginning (using the same rows in X as in the firsh BN layer), just adding new `gamma` and `beta` parameters, or we do it from scratch for every layers's input?

Hope, my question is clear.

Comment: Did you try to implement this? If yes, then also post the error/problem you are facing?

Comment: No, I didn't try to implement it, I just want to understand the particular moment of algorithm

Comment: You do not have to keep the batch size constant.